# Property of sequence of remainders

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers, factoring

The following proof needs verification:

Let $a, b, r \in [0, m-1]$ be integers, $m$ a prime, where

$$
r = ab - qm
$$

is a non-negative remainder, and $q$ some non-negative integer.

**This is where the proof starts:**

Given $a$, assume there are two distinct $b \neq b'$ and $q \neq q'$ such that

$$
ab - qm = ab' - q'm.
$$

Then

$$
a(b - b')/(q - q') = m
$$

is either wrong for $b - b' \le q - q'$, or $m$ is not a prime, since a factorization exists.

Hence, if $m$ is prime, for all two $b \neq b'$ the remainders are different.

Comment: What is the question here? Do you want verification your proof is correct? In that case, I feel like you need some elaboration why $m=a(b-b')/(q-q')$ implies $m$ is not prime, but for the rest it seems fine.

Comment: If this is a proof verification, delineate the statement to be proven from your own attempted proof.

Comment: Hint: prime $\,m\mid a(b-b')\iff m\mid a\ $ or $\ m\mid b-b'\ \ $